# Not able to see the homepage of oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

I installed oracle 10g dbms. I used it a couple of times before. But now when i'm trying to open the database home page, it is showing webpage not available. i can able to access it via command prompt. But how can i make the home page to work?
I'm using windows 32 bit. OS: XP

Comment: Are you trying at this address? `https://localhost:1158/em/console/logon/logon`

Comment: Ya tried jus now. Still the same

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `dbconsole` process is running as documented in the section
[Starting and Stopping the Database Control Console Process](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/em_manage.htm#autoId3).